# Xamarin android Bluetooth communication

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth

I need to connect to some microcontroller devices (sensor chips) over bluetooth and perform data reading and sending.

I have seen some samples which help in discovering, pairing and connecting to bluetooth enabled devices but nothing much for data communication.

My app needs to talk to sensor chips which will not have UI.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how's your sensor chips works. So i have to assume you have read your sensor chip API documents.  I have modified my code which i used to connect to another bluetooth device. It maybe different from yours.

```
BlueToothManager bm;  // --> sensor chip manager

// Configure BlueToothManager.
        bm= new BlueToothManager (this);


private void initBluetooth() {
        // Check if device supports Bluetooth Low Energy.
        if (!bm.hasBluetooth()) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Device does not have Bluetooth Low Energy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        // If Bluetooth is not enabled, let user enable it.
        if (!bm.isBluetoothEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, Constant.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {
            Log.v(this.getClass(), "---> bluetooth already is enabled");
            startBMService();   // --> this function should be from your sensor chip api documents.
        }
    }
```

btw, you also has to register your service on manifest file. below is a sample code. Do not copy, the info should be from your sensor device api documents.

```
<service
            android:name=".Service.BMService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.bm.sdk.service.BMService"
            android:exported="false" />
```